# explicitly listening for signals

Tags: qt, signals, signals-slots

I'm new to Qt, but I have some experience in C and Java.
I'm trying to write a program that makes multiple TCP connections to different servers on the network.
the ip's are read in from a text file and i use connectToHost to establish a connection then the socket is added to a QList. this happens in a loop.

the problem is that i only start receiving the connected() signals when the program exits the loop, this causes some unexpected behaviour.
so  is there a way to poll for signals in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` inside your loop to avoid freezing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected()`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected